# MySQL inner join - How to specify the "main" table with inner join?

Tags: mysql, join

I'm trying to join 3 tables in 1 query. 1 of the fields I want to get is user avatar, which should be received 10 times for 10 different users.

In my query it seems it's grouping the results by user avatars as it duplicates the rest of the info.

Example of what it does:

Title 1
user:1

Title 1
user: 2

Example of what I want:

Title 1
user:1, user:2

This is the query I'm using:

```
select raffle.*, raffle_in.*, user.avatar
from raffle
inner join raffle_in
on raffle.id=raffle_in.raffle_id
inner join user 
on raffle_in.user_id=user.id
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you make group of raffle_id ?

Try add :

group by raffle_in.raffle_id